# How to save unknown size structure (for later retrieval)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct

My plan is to store a couple dozen rows with 2 items per row and both items will have a different data type. Not sure if this is the right approach and have heard about using vectors but I can't find any samples that will take in 2 items with different types with many rows (an unknown amount of rows) similar to what I'm trying to do here. The following doesn't compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct movies_t {
  string title;
  int year;
} myRecNo[];

void printmovie (movies_t movie);

int main ()
{
  string mystr;

  for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    switch (i)
    {
    case 1:
      myRecNo[i].title = "2001 A Space Odyssey";
      myRecNo[i].year = 1968;

      cout << "Auto entry is:\n ";
      printmovie (myRecNo[i]);
      break;
    case 2:
      myRecNo[i].title = "2002 A Space Odyssey";
      myRecNo[i].year = 1978;

      cout << "Auto entry is:\n ";
      printmovie (myRecNo[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void printmovie (movies_t movie)
{
  cout << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Test1.obj||error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct movies_t * myRecNo" (?myRecNo@@3PAUmovies_t@@A) referenced in function _main|
```

Comment: If you want an array of size 2, why not make it an array of size 2?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a container that can store many items, where an item is comprised of a `string` and an `int`. Is this correct?

Comment: You can use use std::vector<std::pair<Type1, Type2>> to get the result u want. std::pair can store two objects with different type in a single data structure and use an array to store the pairs

Comment: @Tas Yes thanks you are right

Comment: @Zhou, I will have to look around for an example like that. More specifically how to retrieve data back out of it too.

Comment: @MickeyD check out my answer below to see how to use vector and pair together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of bad practices in your code, if you are just asking for a way to modify the program so that it will compile and work, see the following:

1. Declare struct and create struct variables in your main function.

   `struct movies_t 
   {
       string title;
       int year;
   };`

then, in your main function, `movies_t myRecNo[2];`

2. Arrays start at index 0, not 1. so your switch should be

   ```
   switch (i)
   {
   case 0:
       myRecNo[i].title = "2001 A Space Odyssey";
       myRecNo[i].year = 1968;

       cout << "Auto entry is:\n ";
       printmovie(myRecNo[i]);
       break;
   case 1:
       myRecNo[i].title = "2002 A Space Odyssey";
       myRecNo[i].year = 1978;

       cout << "Auto entry is:\n ";
       printmovie(myRecNo[i]);
       break;
   }
   // the rest of the code..
   ```

After you modify these, your code should work.

---

However, for a better data structure to save an array of paired values, you can use `std::vector<std::pair<string, int>> myReg` to save your data.

the following code should be much much better, remember to `#include <vector>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void printmovie(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg;

    myReg.push_back({ "2001 A Space Odyssey", 1968 });
    myReg.push_back({ "2002 A Space Odyssey", 1978 }); // <- if your compiler is not using c++11 standard or above, please change this line to myReg.push_back(std::pair<std::string, int>("name of the movie", int)); to use to older version of Initializer 

    printmovie(myReg);
    return 0;
}

void printmovie(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> movie)
{
    for (auto itor = movie.begin(); itor != movie.end(); ++itor)
    {
        //first is the first data in the pair, which is the title
        //second is the second data in the pair, which is the year
        std::cout << (*itor).first  << " (" << (*itor).second << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will try that code out and I'm also interested in trying the vector option also. Do you know of anywhere I can find a small example of paired values like that with adding the data and maybe printing/displaying output

Comment: @MickeyD you can check out cplusplus.com and search pair, it will provide you with detailed explanation on std::pair and examples :) that's where I usually learn

Comment: Yes the first structure solution does compile above but I'm going to use it for storing unknown size vector which needs to be dynamic and I thought putting [] brackets would allow me to do that but `movies_t myRecNo[];` throws an error `error C2133: 'myRecNo' : unknown size`. I need to now test out the second method you mentioned.

Comment: @MickeyD std::vector is dynamic array, so you can store as many pair of objects as you want as long as your memory is enough. Declaring an array as int a[] will not make it dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd example.  The vector solution gives me this `error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'`

Comment: @MickeyD did you #include vector? Try copy paste my whole set of codes into your compiler, and check if there is any missing comma/parenthesis/braces haha cause I hand typed the code

Comment: @MickeyD and check which line gives you the error, if it is the push_back gives you the error, most likely your compiler is not using c++11 standard or above, the you should myReg.push_back(std::pair<std::string, int>("title of the movie", 1978));

Comment: I copied the full vector sample you gave which includes the #include <vector>.  I had many problems installing visual studio so I am using code::blocks ide and that is using visual C++ 2010. Not sure where I can find out what standard you mean about the standard.  But good news is you must be right above the version since changing the code like you said with the change works. Great Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully quick question regarding the vector code. If I had 10 rows, how can i only extract for example row 5?

Comment: @MickeyD if the vector name is myReg, just use myReg[4] will give you the pair in row 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134938/discussion-between-mickey-d-and-zhou-zhi-hua).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone & @Zhou.

Zhou's code above might work on a newer version of the compiler but I'm using Code::Blocks IDE with MS Visual C++ 2010 compiler.

Here is the vector method that worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

void printmovie(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>>);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> myReg;

    myReg.push_back(std::pair<std::string, int>("title of the movie", 1968));
    myReg.push_back(std::pair<std::string, int>("title of the movie2", 1978));
    //myReg.push_back({ "2001 A Space Odyssey", 1968 });
    //myReg.push_back({ "2002 A Space Odyssey", 1978 });

    printmovie(myReg);
    //or to print a single element (the 2nd row) thanks @zhou
    std::cout << myReg[1].first << " " << myReg[1].second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void printmovie(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> movie)
{
    for (auto itor = movie.begin(); itor != movie.end(); ++itor)
    {
        //first is the first data in the pair, which is the title
        //second is the second data in the pair, which is the year
        std::cout << (*itor).first  << " (" << (*itor).second << ")\n";
    }
}
```